# filter dataframe based on condition on another column in the dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset, data-manipulation

I want to filter the following R dataframe based on a condition i.e. if column "Score" does not have an A within the same ID, delete the rows associated with the ID. For example, for ID number 2, there are only C and B but no A. So drop the rows with ID no 2.

```
 dat <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    Score = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L
    ), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Info = c(1L, 
    10L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

```
dat
   ID Score Info
1   1     A    1
2   1     A   10
3   1     B    7
4   2     C    8
5   2     B    9
6   2     B    1
7   3     B    7
8   3     C    8
9   3     C    3
10  3     A    2
```

Output will be as follows:

```
       ID  Score Info
1     1     A    1
2     1     A    10
3     1     B    7
4     3     B    7
5     3     C    8
6     3     C    3
7     3     A    2
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with `dplyr`. You can do

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter("A" %in% Score)
```